# Font Awesome 5 - Improving performance with JS SVG replacement?

Tags: javascript, performance, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome 5 with a limited set of icons (around 30). I minify the javascript version of FA to remove all unused icons. This brings the file size of js/all.min.js to around 116kb.

I'm still seeing major performance issues, i think they are related to layout / dom trashing, could this possible be due to the  replacement to ?

Any suggestions on how to improve the performance here? Or am i looking at the wrong spot?

**Source HTML:**

```
<i class="fa fa-shield"></i>
```

**Browser Renders HTML:**

```
 <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-shield fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="shield" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M466.5 83.7l-192-80a48.15 48.15 0 0 0-36.9 0l-192 80C27.7 91.1 16 108.6 16 128c0 198.5 114.5 335.7 221.5 380.3 11.8 4.9 25.1 4.9 36.9 0C360.1 472.6 496 349.3 496 128c0-19.4-11.7-36.9-29.5-44.3z">
    </path>
 </svg>
 <!-- <i class="fa fa-shield"></i> -->
```

Site for anyone interested: https://www.lasereyeinstitute.com/

Answer (score 0):

The main fontawesome css (https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css) has a total size of 55.51kb maybe you could use that one and compare instead of using a js version.